# $L^\infty$ and Sobolev spaces

Tags: partial-differential-equations, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces

I am studying Sobolev spaces, and my professors give us the following exercise, but I do not understand how is possible conclude it.

Let $1\leq p< \infty$ and $v\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$. If
$$ |v(x)|^p\leq p || v ||_p^{p-1} || v' ||_p ,$$
then there existe $C>0$, such that
$$ || v ||_\infty \leq C ||v||_{W^{1,p}}.$$

**How is possible proof it ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall Young's inequality: for $\alpha, \beta \in [0,1]$ with $\alpha + \beta = 1$, one has $a^{\alpha}b^{\beta} \leq \alpha a + \beta b$ for any non-negative real numbers $a$ and $b$. Take in this case $\alpha = (p-1)/p$, $\beta = 1/p$, $a = ||v||^{p}_{p}$, $b = ||v'||^{p}_{p}$.

From the  condition and the above inequality, you have that:
\begin{equation}
|v(x)|^p \leq p||v||^{p \times \frac{p-1}{p}}_{p} ||v'||^{p \times \frac{1}{p}}_{p} \leq p \left( \frac{p-1}{p} ||v||_{p}^{p} + \frac{1}{p} ||v'||_{p}^{p} \right) \leq C(p)||v||_{W^{1,p}}^{p},
\end{equation}
where $C(p) = p \max\{ (p-1)/p, 1/p\}$.
By continuity and compactness, take the $p$-th root, then the supremum over all $x$ to conclude.

Comment: You do not need Young's inequality here. You can just estimate the right-hand side of the first inequality in the OP by $C \|v\|_{W^{1,p}}^p$.